# XAML list value setter with pre-existing items

Tags: c#, list, xaml, setter

I'm working on a C# WPF component (with VS2010 Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel), which contains public properties like int and List.

The component seems to be serialized by VS2010 wpf editor fine as the resulting xml-block in the .xaml is like:

```
<Parent>
    <NumberProperty>10</NumberProperty>
    <ListProperty>
        <Item>
            blah
        </Item>
    </ListProperty>
</Parent>
```

When deserializing the component (i.e. run the application), the List property is read (runs getter) and item is added to it. No setter is run for the list.

Problem is that the list contains purposely default item, which is added to the list at the item parent constructor. These/this pre-existing item(s) should be replaced by the item(s) in the list, if any is available in the related xaml.

I tried `DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)` as the list attribute with no luck.

So is it possible to tell by some attribute to the environment, that it should replace the list property (call the setter) instead of adding items to it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a head scratcher :)

As you say, if you initialise a list property with some default values, they don't appear in the designer.  If you add some values to the list, they're serialized to .xaml and then these values are added to your default values at run-time instead of replacing them.

*One* solution is to use a custom collection that knows it contains a default value (or values) and removes it (or them) when the first new item is added to the list.

e.g.

```
public partial class UserControl1
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        // initialise collection with '1' - doesn't appear in design time properties
        Ids = new MyCollection<int>(1);

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public MyCollection<int> Ids { get; set; }
}

public class MyCollection<T> : Collection<T>
{
    private readonly T _defaultValue;
    private bool _hasDefaultValue;

    public MyCollection(T defaultValue)
    {
        _defaultValue = defaultValue;

        try
        {
            _hasDefaultValue = false;

            Add(defaultValue);
        }
        finally
        {
            _hasDefaultValue = true;
        }
    }

    protected override void InsertItem(int index, T item)
    {
        base.InsertItem(index, item);

        if (_hasDefaultValue)
        {
            Remove(_defaultValue);
            _hasDefaultValue = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Xaml

```
    <local:UserControl1 Id="5">
        <local:UserControl1.Ids>
            <System:Int32>2</System:Int32>
            <System:Int32>3</System:Int32>
            <System:Int32>4</System:Int32>
        </local:UserControl1.Ids>
    </local:UserControl1>
```

I can't say it's a particularly pleasing solution, but I think it does solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you :) I was a bit afraid that it has to be done by code. For end user perspective (in my case), it might be nice to add an internal constructor, which set '_hasDefaultValue' to true and other constructors not. But this still summons troubles as one can't tell whether parameterless constructor was called by user or by xaml-loader. And I'd rather not change the container as previous version is at use already.. I tried similar approach at the list getter, which empties the list, if the component is not yet enough initialized (ugly). Needs a bit more digging.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old issue, one sort of solution was found long time ago, but anyway. Should use list to add items, so the list will be replaced. Like so:

```
<Parent>
<NumberProperty>10</NumberProperty>
<ListProperty>
    <List>
        <Item>
            blah
        </Item>
    </List>
</ListProperty>
```